# if constexpr() gives an error in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

I have read about `constexpr` in C++17 using this [reference](https://tech.io/playgrounds/2205/7-features-of-c17-that-will-simplify-your-code/constexpr-if) link.

Then, I made C++ program to test `constexpr` :

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 10;

int func() 
{
    if constexpr (i == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (i > 0)
        return i;
    else
        return -1;
}

int main() 
{
    int ret = func();
    std::cout<<"Ret : "<<ret<<std::endl;
}
```

But, compiler give an error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int func()':
main.cpp:8:25: error: the value of 'i' is not usable in a constant expression
     if constexpr (i == 0)
                         ^
main.cpp:4:5: note: 'int i' is not const
 int i = 10;
```

Why gives an error?

Comment: Probably because b `i` is not a compile-time constant (as noted in the error message!).

Comment: Because *"the value of 'i' is not usable in a constant expression"*. What's unclear about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of `if constexpr`. This is not a test for const expression to be performed at runtime, it is a test of a logical expression to be performed at compile time.

The construct is roughly similar to `#if` of preprocessor, in that the other branch is eliminated, along with code that may otherwise not compile.

This will work:

```
template<int  i>
int func() 
{
    if constexpr (i == 0)
        return 0;
    else if constexpr (i > 0)
        return i;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

The compiler knows the value of `i` at compile time, so depending on its value only one of the three branches is going to remain in the compiled code.

Comment: isnt is up to the compiler to decide if it is evaluated at runtime or compile time? If yes, then it cannot eliminate the other branches. What I actually want to know: is it really ok to write something like `int foo() { if constexpr (1==0) { return "this is the wrong type"; } else { return 0;} }` ?

Comment: @tobi303 This is the whole point of `if constexpr` that the remaining branch must be eliminated at compile time. Your code should absolutely compile. Moreover, you can use `auto` for the return type, and decide on the const condition which type you are going to return. According to specification, this should work.

Comment: @tobi303 Part of the reason to have this is so we can actually write code like `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>)` and it actually works instead of having to use SFINAE.  See this example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fd12ae025b3ac0c

Answer (score 5):

`if constexpr ( condition )` works compile time, so `condition` must be evaluable compile time.

`int i = 0` isn't a constant variable, so `i == 0` isn't evaluable compile time.

Try with `int const i = 0` or, better, `constexpr int i = 0`.